# Appcelerator view hiding animation

Tags: animation, view, hide, appcelerator

I am trying to integrate animation in a module where, when the dismiss button is clicked, the entire pendingTasksBar view's height turn to 0dp but at a stretch of 300ms. This is what i have tried so far. Can someone please help me out here?

```
function hidePendingTasksBar(){
    log.trace("[tasks]  >>  [hidePendingTasksBar]");

    var animationObj = Ti.UI.createAnimation({
        height : "0dp",
        duration : 300
    });
    $.pendingTasksBar.animate(animationObj);
    //.pendingTasksBar.height = "0dp";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Height property must be a Number, and you are using a String. I think that's the problem. Try using 0 instead of "0dp".

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Animation-property-height

Answer (score 0):

Setting height to 0 as number should work. And if it doesn't work, then you can safely use matrix transformation to decrease height or to increase it to same height again as below:

```
var matrix = Ti.UI.create2DMatrix();
matrix = matrix.scale(1, 0);

// to decrease height
$.pendingTasksBar.animate({
    duration : 300,
    transform : matrix
});


// to reset height
$.pendingTasksBar.animate({
    duration : 300,
    transform : Ti.UI.create2DMatrix()   // use empty matrix & it will reset original matrix or UI.
});
```